# PHP MySQL query - select all users but only display the earliest logon times for each user

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by, where-clause

I want to be able to bring back the earliest logon time per user, so only 1 record (the earliest record) displays for each user

I've tried various ways of `GROUP BY` but can't seem to get it quite right (if that is actually the correct way of doing). `username` is the unique value which can be used to GROUP BY

Here's the code I'm currently working with..

```
SELECT username, name, logon, added FROM data WHERE (date(added) LIKE '$date') AND (logon = (SELECT MIN(logon) FROM data))
```

I've also tried (below) but only get one result back, only displaying one user

```
WHERE (date(added) LIKE '$date') AND logon = (SELECT MIN(logon) FROM data)
```

The first image is what I'm currently getting, the second image is how I want my results to display, please see below

---

Let me know if you require anymore information, I've tried to put as much as possible

Thanks,
Tom

---

[image: table]

### [image: result]

---

Comment: And where's the image that shows what you have to begin with. Or is reverse engineering a part of the puzzle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.  Your query needs a correlation clause:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM data d
WHERE date(d.added) = '$date' AND 
      d.logon = (SELECT MIN(d2.logon) FROM data d2 WHERE d2.name = d.name);
```

Note:  The logic for `added` is confusing.  First, you should not use `like` with dates.  And, for that matter, you should not be inserting parameter values into the string, you should be using query parameters.  And, actually, I don't see the need for that column; your question doesn't mention `added`.

Comment: that's spot on! thank you very much!!

I can accept the answer in 5mins it states

Comment: added was the datetime it was inserted. I'm working on an existing DB with poor column names

Comment: how would I change this into **added** and **logon** = **$data**

Comment: `WHERE date(d.added) = '$date'` i would like it to include `logon = '$date'` as well as `added`

Comment: @Billo . . . If adding it to the outer `where` clause doesn't do the trick, then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

use this query , problem will be solved

```
SELECT username, min(logontime) FROM data where date(logontime) = '2016-08-10' group by username
```

Comment: I think he want the entire row where the logontime is the minimum one.

Comment: isn't working within my PHP page, although I've just tested it in MySQL and it works! must be failing somewhere else. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
<?php 

$users = array();
$sql = "select * from users";
$result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);//$conn is your connection object
while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if(!in_array($user['name'],$users)){
        $users[$user['name']]=$user['logOnTime'];//replace key names with your table row names
    }
}
//$users is an array that has your user names as key and their last logon time as value
 ?>
```